# Change TYPE to ENGINE (different MySQL version)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I backup and restore my data but it's say:

```
to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line...
```

Because diffrent mysql version, and need only change: **TYPE=MyISAM** to **ENGINE=MyISAM**

Is there a command I can run to change the type of my current tables use **TYPE=MyISAM** to use **ENGINE=MyISAM**?

A big database file, that i can't open by text editor to edit.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing, select the proper MySQL version from the `SQL compatibility mode` dropdown. Looks like MYSQL40 would work for you in this case.

[image]

You could also use sed (or Perl, Python, awk, etc) to manipulate the file directly. First do a sanity check with `grep "TYPE=" foo.sql` to make sure you don't have actual data with "TYPE=" anywhere in it, then the actual replacement with `sed -e 's/TYPE=/ENGINE=/' foo.sql > newfoo.sql`. But selecting the proper dropdown is easier.